# Angular Custom Pipe Arguments

Tags: angular, arguments, pipe

I have a custom Pipe where I am passing text along with some arguments 
Here I am passing a text like "My name is %name%" which will get transformed to 
"My name is {{name}}"
in the arguments I am passing name:"ABC" how do I replace {{name}} to ABC that I am passing in the arguments.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'; 
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({   name: 'textTransform' }) 
export class textTransform implements PipeTransform {   
    constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}   

    transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
        let val = [];
        value = value.replace(/%.*?%/g, m => { m = m.slice(1, -1); 
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);   
    }
}
```

args is an array of key values like a`rgs[0].name="abc", args[0].age=11` 
so if the string is `"My Name is {{name}} and I am {{age}} years old"` should be transformed to `"My Name is abc and I am 10 years old"`

Comment: I have add another solution base of object instead of array choose the one fit your need 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update the transform method like this the syntax error

```
 transform(value: any, args?: any[]): any {
        const result= value.replace(/%.*?%/g, m => m.slice(1,m.length-1)); 
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(result);   
    }
```

as far I understand  you need to pass a new parameter for the name and do the replacment

```
 transform(value: any, name:string): any {
        let val = [];
        value = value.replace(/%.*?%/g, m => name); 
        return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);   
    }
```

template

```
{{ 'My name is %name%' | name:'ABC' }} => My name is ABC
```

**Updated!**

in case the replacment values is an array and  base string has a location like `%target%` this sould do it

```
  transform(value: any, values: string[] =[]): any {
    let  result  = value;
    for(let val  of values ) {
     result = result.replace(/%.*?%/, (m) => val);
    }
    return (result);
  }
```

> the order replacment values is mater here

template

```
{{ 'My name is %name%' | name:['ABC','15'] }} => My name is ABC 
{{ 'My name is %name% and and age %age%' | name:['ABC','15'] }} => My name is ABC and and age 15
{{ 'My name is %replace% and and age %replace%' | name:['ABC','15'] }} => My name is ABC and and age 15
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qf5taw)

Comment: basically args is an array so it will have values like args[0].name, args[0].age etc

Comment: Hi @Jay  did I got your problem correctly ,can you give an example like in html what you pass and what your desired result

Comment: @Jay `args` will be the first paramater you pass th the pipe name :'something' so args will be something

Comment: I just updated the question with the arguments part.

Comment: it 's  can be solved without lodash I am still wonder about your data structure ,and you can check the arguments object will give all function passed paraqmater 

Comment: yes args is an array so whatever values we pass there needs to be replaced in the string like args[0].name = "abc", args[0].age = 10 etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195232/discussion-between-malbarmawi-and-jay).

Answer (score 1):

another approach is instead of passing an array of values where the replace base on the order we can pass an object of property as the replacement values this more cleaner not restrict based on the order if you have more than one place with the same value you don't need to duplicate the values in case of array like `['abc',15,15]`

```
  transform(value: any, values: any = {}): any {
    let result = value;

    result = result.replace(/%.*?%/g, (m) => {
      const prop = m.slice(1, m.length - 1);
      return values[prop] || '' 
    })
    return result
  }
```

*template*

```
{{ 'My name is %name%' | name:{name:'ABC',age : 15} }}
{{ 'My name is %name% and and age %age%' | name: {name:'ABC',age : 15} }}
```

> **%age%** need to have a proprty with the name **age** , and you need to provide uniq names like `'my name is %name% from %name% country'`
>   so theis will not work and the it has to be this way `'my name is %name% from %countryName% country'` with object like this as parameter
>   `{name:'malbarmawi' , countryName :'Turkey'}`

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9pnus)

Comment: @Jay happy to help  